# What is the new extension feature in Tableau about? Can you name a useful example?

Tags: tableau-api

As the title says, I am not talking about the file extension but the new feauture added.

Thanks.

Comment: Look online at Tableau's website. They have dozens of explanations and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The Extension feature allows you to use the Extension APIs in Tableau.  There are some interesting ones.  I like the Data-Driven Parameters.  The Extension Gallery is worth checking out. https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/